# Swift xcframework with cocoapod embed (GoogleMap) build successfully, but on usage, it got error "Failed to build module ...."

Tags: swift, xcframework

I'm trying to create a .xcframework that needs to use third-party pods (GoogleMap, etc) inside that framework.

I built the .xcframework successfully with terminal command:

```
xcodebuild archive \
-workspace CustomXCFramework.xcworkspace \
-scheme CustomXCFramework \
-archivePath ./archives/ios.xcarchive \
-sdk iphoneos \
-SKIP_INSTALL=NO \
-BUILD_LIBRARY_FOR_DISTRIBUTION=YES

xcodebuild archive \
-workspace CustomXCFramework.xcworkspace \
-scheme CustomXCFramework \
-archivePath ./archives/ios-sim.xcarchive \
-sdk iphonesimulator \
-SKIP_INSTALL=NO \
-BUILD_LIBRARY_FOR_DISTRIBUTION=YES

xcodebuild -create-xcframework \
-framework ./archives/ios-sim.xcarchive/Products/Library/Frameworks/CustomXCFramework.framework \
-framework ./archives/ios.xcarchive/Products/Library/Frameworks/CustomXCFramework.framework \
-output ./builds/CustomXCFramework.xcframework
```

But when I tried to use the framework on my Demo Project, it shows the error

```
Failed to build module 'CustomXCFramework' from its module interface; it may have been damaged or it may have triggered a bug in the Swift compiler when it was produced
```

[image: Framework Project]
[image: Demo Project Error]